# error while uploading arduino code avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno, serial-communication, arduino-nano

I am trying to upload the Arduino code in Arduino Nano but I am getting the error

```
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync
```

I tried several things to reset the Arduino. 
The RX tx pin is not sorted, nor is the bootloader burn working. 
Any answers to try?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good list to work through trouble shooting this error:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won